# Querying related fields from Django Tables with One to Many Relationship

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am just exploring how to get around with Django, and i created two models in my Django app.

```
from django.db import models

#first model
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.name

#second model
class Skill(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    skill = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    years = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.skill, self.person
```

The first model is **Person** and the second model is **Skill**. Now how the relation goes is that each Person will have many skills.

Now I can update the database with the data, the admin section of the site also works fine.

On the Django Shell, I try to run the command:

```
Skill.object.all()
```

and what i get is the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 235, in __repr__
    return '<QuerySet %r>' % data
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 572, in __repr__
    u = six.text_type(self)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type tuple)
```

or if i try the command:

```
Skill.objects.get(pk=1)
```

i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 572, in __repr__
    u = six.text_type(self)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type tuple)
```

However if i run a command such as :

```
 Skill.objects.get(skill='Photoshop').person.name
```

I get the name of the person who has the skill "Photoshop."

I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong here; maybe I am not supposed to query a table with the foreign key this way? Or maybe I am doing something wrong.

Well, finally what I like to query is, I want to find *all the skills of a Person with a given name or primary key*.

Comment: Are you sure the above code is copy pasted? Is there any `comma` at end of `return self.skill` ?Then query is `Person.objects.get(id="id").skill_set.all()`

Comment: yes the code is copy pasted, and no there is no comma at the end of `return self.skill` :(

Comment: @itzmeontv i am sorry there was a comma, actually i had removed the comma and tried, but i guess the change did not apply, until i quit the shell and restarted it, i thought simply saving the file would have been enough. Anyways i have updated the code with how it was with the comma.

Comment: so i have now changed `return self.skill, self.person` to `return self.skill` and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__str__` should return a `str`. So Change something like this

```
return self.skill, self.person
```

to

```
return "%s-%s" %(self.skill, self.person.name)
```

Comment: oh thank you, i was just going to ask, how do i fix that if i had to keep the person information aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Your `__str__` method returns a tuple (self.skill, self.person), it must return those object's str representation. In order to achieve that, change:

```
return self.skill, self.person
```

to

```
return "{}, {}".format(self.skill, self.person)
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining, now i understand it :)

Comment: Good luck exploring Django :)